# Active Keyframe Panel is not showing in the graph editor

Tags: animation, properties, graph-editor

I have selected a keyframe in the graph editor and I want to view it's properties.

1. I selected keyframes in the graph editor.
2. Pressed N key and tried pulling out the side arrow.
3. Instead of getting the "Active Keyframe Panel" I'm getting the "show cursor" option.

Is there something I can do to get the Active Keyframe Panel seen in the link below:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/properties.html#id3

See my attached screen shot of what I get when I press N in the graph editor.

[image: Don't see the Active Keyframe Panel]

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  I was selecting the channel group folder instead of the actual channel itself.